# pandas dataframe's `apply` slow when applied on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with an index of type `DatetimeIndex` with parameters: `dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DateTime', length=324336, freq=None`. The dataframe has 22 columns, all numerical.
I want to create a new column `Date` with only the date-part of `DateTime` (to be used for grouping later).

My first attempt

```py
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.name.date(), axis=1)
```

takes ca. 13.5 seconds.
But when I make `DateTime` a regular column, it goes faster, even including the index operations:

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['DateTime'].date(), axis=1)
df.set_index('DateTime')
```

This takes ca. 6.3 s, i.e., it is twice as fast. Furthermore, applying `apply` directly on the series (since it depends only on one column) is faster still:

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['Date'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda dt: dt.date())
df.set_index('DateTime')
```

takes ca. 1.1 s, more than 10 times faster than the original solution.

This brings me to my questions:

1. Is applying `apply` on a series generally faster than doing it on the dataframe?
2. Is using `apply` on an index generally slower than on columns?
3. More general: what is the advantage of keeping a column as an index? Or, conversely, what would I loose by resetting the index before doing any operations?
4. Finally, is there an even better/faster way of adding the column?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) what should be faster solution:

```
df['Date'] = df.index.date
```

> Is applying apply on a series generally faster than doing it on the dataframe?
>   Is using apply on an index generally slower than on columns

I think `apply` are loops under the hood, so it is obviously slowier like pandas methods

---

> More general: what is the advantage of keeping a column as an index? Or, conversely, what would I loose by resetting the index before doing any operations?

You can check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html):

> Identifies data (i.e. provides metadata) using known indicators, important for analysis, visualization, and interactive console display.
>   Enables automatic and explicit data alignment.
>   Allows intuitive getting and setting of subsets of the data set.

Also if working time timeseries there are many methods like `resample` working with `DatetimeIndex`, also is possible use [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#indexing) with `DatetimeIndex`.

Comment: So, there is no numerical advantage to having an index, only disadvantages? As for the second link, I do not see how it answers the question. By the way, I already use DatetimeIndex - I have updated my question with precise type information

Comment: @MichalKaut - hmmm, what do you think `only disadvantages` ?

Comment: well, working with index was slower in my test and I do not see anything in your answer that shows where it is faster (to work with index); by the way, `df.index.date` is faster than any of my solutions, but still does not answer why `apply` is slow on index...

Comment: @MichalKaut - hmmm, `Is using apply on an index generally slower than on columns?` I think `apply` is not defined for index, in your code is always use `DataFrame.apply`

Comment: good point (even though the 3rd example actually uses `apply` on Series) - I guess I should have written "using index vs columns" inside `apply`..

Comment: @MichalKaut - hmmm, I think it is better ask in pandas github, because it is more question for developers